# Multibootable USB with windows, linux and iso

Tags: linux, boot, usb, partitioning, iso-image

I want to create a multibootable usb, that will contain some `linux` distros, some `windows` ones as well as some non-OS iso(such as Hiren's boot DVD, Parted Magic bootble CD etc).

As far as multi-bootable-linux distros, I know `Yumi`.

I thought of partitioning the usb drive and make multibootable, by making it multipartinioned and having each distro in one partition. Can that be achieved?

I also don't know how to make the Hyren's and Parted Magic's `.iso`'s bootable in a USB.

Ideally there would be a bootloader(like `Grub`) that would help to choose wich "partition" to run from.

Can all or part these be achieved?

Comment: USB sticks are cheap so the simplest option would be to have one per individual operating system, or is that just being defeatist? 8-)

Comment: @Richard: You are right;they are cheap. But right now I am having about 6 usb drives, which isn't very convenient, as you can imagine.

Comment: I've tried to set up several different bootable partitions before, and some BIOSs did not like it and wouldn't boot from any of them. Especially Macs. Maybe MultiSystem fixes the issue though

Answer (score 1):

It's rather old question, but for anyone who stubled upon it in the future i will provide a way better answer(atleast in my opinion)

The best utility for that exact task as of 2023 is Ventoy(https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html). It is an open source tool that creates two partitions on your selected drive. One is used to load the *main part* of the tool itself upon bootup(you don't really need to fidle with it), the other one is used to store iso/wim/vhd(x)/img/efi files that you want to be able to select from. You just drop the images you want to be able to boot from and you are ready to go! No more configuration needed, it will just provide you a grub menu from which you will be able to select the desired image(or an elf)

So basically it is batteries included drag&drop solution that works for most image formats(as well as elf), it can also update itself without removing the already written roms via desktop utility. I don't think there is another one like this.
Used it myself a few times already with windows and linux - it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using MultiSystem (http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/ http://liveusb.info/dotclear/).

I haven't actually tested it with Windows on a flash drive because I don't use Windows, but it claims to work with Windows and nearly any GNU/Linux live cd I tried worked with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side note for those of you who haven't tried this, and found out the hard way (grudge) yet, it requires that you use a FAT32 formatted flash drive, with a label consisting of **no** spaces.